# wifi driver for Macbook Pro 2013 on debian 12

Tags: debian, wifi, gnome, drivers, macintosh

I have installed Debian 12 on my Macbook Pro 2013 via an internet connection with the thunderbolt adapter. It did not automatically install the wifi driver -- at least in the preferences there is no Wifi item in the menu.

I ran `lspci -vnn | grep -i net` to check what kind of wifi device I have. The output is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0112]
3c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1682]
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter [106b:00f6]
```

I have checked many sources that provide some instructions. However, nothing has worked so far. For example
`apt install broadcom-sta-dkms` and `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer` do not work both respond with `unable to locate package`.

I am surprised because I thought that non-free software is automatically included in Debian 12. And also when I check `/etc/apt/sources.list` I get these lines;

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
```

So I am out of ideas. How do I get the wifi to work?